# iOS Xcode, how to ensure nothing "sensitive" exists within an .IPA?

Tags: ios, xcode, security, ipa

I've been asked to review an app packaged as .IPA. I'm [using this tutorial to see the package contents](http://osxdaily.com/2011/04/07/extract-and-explore-an-ios-app-in-mac-os-x/). The app is packaged for app store distribution

- Is there a way to get any info out of **compiled storyboards**? *.storyboardc
- Can I extract anything from the **Settings.bundle**?
- Is there any sensitive info within **embedded.mobileprovision** ?
- Can **.PEM or .P12 certificates** be extracted and used for malicious purposes?

**Is there anything else I can do to verify that the app has no sensitive information?**